# Using Matlab imfindcircles function to find circles

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I try to find the all coins show in the image by using Matlab function imfindcircles. But it doesn't work!

[image]

Here is my code:

```
I = imread('coins.jpg');
imshow(I);
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(I, [70,170],'Sensitivity',.95);
centerStrongs= centers(:,:);
radiiStrongs = radii(:);
viscircles(centerStrongs, radiiStrongs, 'EdgeColor','b');
```

by using imdistline i know the radius of coins are between (70,170)

Comment: what does you output look like?

Comment: I guess the contrast of the relatively bright coins on the relatively bright background does make it quite difficult to solve the problem. Also the lighting of your scene creates shaddows of the coins which are also circle segments.  When you compare your case to the matlab documenation example https://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html you see that they use a much clearer scene setting. Please provide your results for further analysis.

Comment: thanks, i could not find any circles actually.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that is does not work ? Try to tune better the sensitivity :

```
I = imread('/home/me/Desktop/coin.jpg');
imshow(I);
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(I, [70,170],'Sensitivity',.98);
centerStrongs= centers(:,:);
radiiStrongs = radii(:);
viscircles(centerStrongs, radiiStrongs, 'EdgeColor','b');
```

I get pretty every coin.
(sorry for not writing this in comment, I have not enough reputation yet)

[image: coins are detected]

Comment: If you expect more accurate result, try to pretreat your image with histogram equalization or other processing stuff like sobel filter.